# Different Page style

Tags: layout, cms

Is it possible that every CMS page has a different layout order? Example, I want on my homepage to have a slider with dome images and below the navigation bar, and below that my logo which I have created. Now, on the other pages i want the navigation bar to be as default, on top of the page with the logo above him. Is this possible to do in magento and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just create different page layouts (under `/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/page`), for each layout that you want.

Just move what you want around in the template files and assign the necessary layouts to the various pages accordingly.

You'd need to register each new layout via a custom extension which [this tutorial](http://rakeshwebdev.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/add-new-custom-page-layout-in-magento-1-7/) explains how to do.